# getTypeName() of NetworkInfo returns mobile eventhough connected to WIFI on mobile device

Tags: android

In the following code, the activeinfo.getTypeName() returns mobile even when connected to wifi. I read somewhere that wifi will not be detected on emulator so I even tried it on my device. But it still returns either mobile - when connected to wifi or mobile data (I even tried turning off the mobile data and just using the wifi instead of turning on both)- and "not connected" when i turn off both the wifi and mobile data.

```
ConnectivityManager conmgr = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeinfo = conmgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    WifiManager wifi=(WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    Log.e("sometag", activeinfo.getTypeName());
    String ssid;

    if(activeinfo!=null && activeinfo.isConnected())
    {
//eventhough the following comparison is wrong, the next else should return "wifi" right? well, it doesn't.

        if(activeinfo.getTypeName()=="WIFI")            {

            WifiInfo w=wifi.getConnectionInfo();
            ssid= w.getSSID();


        }
        else
        {
            ssid = activeinfo.getTypeName();
        }
    }
    else
        ssid= "not connected";
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on this line:

```
if (activeinfo.getTypeName() == "WIFI") {
```

Unlike other programming languages, using the `==` operator for Strings in Java does not produce the generally expected result. That's because it tests for `reference` equality (i.e. the same position in memory) instead of the equality of the content.

Please take a look at [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: But activeinfo.getTypeName() returns mobile in Log and also in else statement. The control doesnt enter the if loop, so I thought i might be making a mistake in comparison, like you said, and hence logged the value before the loop and also the else statement also returns mobile.